# Clubbing several similar repeating mysql SELECT statements

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to fetch classified details from a table. I have *classified_ids* in a csv format. I break them out from CSV and make independent queries for every *classified_id*.

What I am doing right now is:

```
SELECT * from classified WHERE classified_id = 501;

SELECT * from classified WHERE classified_id = 545;

SELECT * from classified WHERE classified_id = 578;
```

..... and so on... executing each one of them.

I feel this is inefficient for a large number of ids. Is there any better way to club all of these statements into one or make it more efficient somehow?

[I am using PHP mysql* (I know its deprecated, its an old project)]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead create an array of your `classified_id` like,

```
$classified_ids = [545, 123, 234];
```

and query using mysql `IN` like,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM classified WHERE classified_id IN ( {implode(',', $classified_ids)} )";
```

will query,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM classified WHERE classified_id IN ( 545, 123, 234 )";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these SQL will useful to you. Please check it

```
 SELECT * FROM classified WHERE classified_id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT classified_id FROM classified)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I actually had the values of classified IDs , I only need to fetch them. Anyway I got the answer, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
SELECT * from classified WHERE classified_id in (545, 123, 234);
```